# HttpClient and JSON with arrays

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to parse JSON file, when I'm doing it with JSON without arrays everything is ok but when I'm trying to do this with JSON with arrays I got unhandled exceptions.

My JSON:

```
{  
   "odata.metadata":"http://212.182.24.861:12345/DataService.svc",
   "value":[  
      {  
         "Event_p":[  

         ],
         "Id":1,
         "Status":0,
         "Name":"test"
      },
      {  
         "Event_p":[  

         ],
         "Id":2,
         "Status":0,
         "Name":"test"
      }
   ]
}
```

My task:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Event>> LoadEvents()
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("address");

    var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Event>>(jsonString);

    return values;
}
```

My model, at this point I want only to get name.

```
public class Event : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Event class definition does not match the structure of the JSON file you are attempting to parse. Perhaps if your JSON looked like the following then it would parse successfully.

[
    {
    "Event_p": [

    ],
    "Id": 1,
    "Status": 0,
    "Name": "test"
},
{
    "Event_p": [

    ],
    "Id": 2,
    "Status": 0,
    "Name": "test"
}
]

Comment: I can't edit JSON, what can I do with my Event class?

Comment: Define a new class with a property called "Value" of type List<Event>, then deserialize the JSON as that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to rewrite your `Event` class, you can also manually parse the JSON response using LINQ to JSON provided by JSON.NET:

```
var parsed = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var events = parsed["value"].Select(
    e => new Event { Name = e["Name"].ToString() });

var values = new ObservableCollection<Event>(events);
```

Or perhaps a little bit cleaner:

```
var values = JObject.Parse(jsonString)["value"].ToObject<ObservableCollection<Event>>();
```